# Sql code give invalid SQL statement in Java but it works in SqlDeveloper

Tags: java, oracle

I tried to make crud , but insert statement do not work from code

```
   try {
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());



        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL2, username, password);

        String sql="INSERT INTO Produce(name,description,Produce_Date,Price,CATEGORY_ID,Person_ID)VALUES('"+name+"','"+description+"',TO_DATE('"+sqlDate+"', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),"+price+","+category_Id+","+person_id+")";

        System.out.println(sql);
        stmt = conn2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        if (conn2 != null && !conn2.isClosed()) {
            conn2.close();
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I made a System.out.println to see my sql and to execute it to understand where is the problem, this is my String, and it works in sqlDeveloper:

```
INSERT INTO Produce(name,description,Produce_Date,Price,CATEGORY_ID,Person_ID)VALUES('ew','rrr',TO_DATE('2018-11-14', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),12.0,2,2)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO Produce(name,description,Produce_Date,Price,CATEGORY_ID,Person_ID) VALUES('"+name+"','"+description+"',TO_DATE('"+sqlDate+"', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),"+price+","+category_Id+","+person_id+") change to this

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal change what? Can you please point the difference out?

Comment: Don't do this, use a prepared statement and pass parameters, this will handle or the escaping for you and ensure your SQL is valid.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer by Vaibhav, the usage of `executeQuery` is wrong for the insert. Have a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/), should be using preparedStatement to avert the risk of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using insert SQL query to retrieve result.

I believe to retrieve name you need to execute select statement